# JButton border set with setBackground()?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

So I have some code to change the background color of a button, but when I use the code, it sets the background color and border color.

[image: Picture]

Is there  a way to not make this happen?

Thanks!

Code:

```
public void highlight(ArrayList<JButton> buttons){
    for (JButton j : buttons) {
    j.setBorder(new JButton().getBorder());
    j.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    j.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    j.setOpaque(true);
    j.setBorderPainted(false);
    j.setFocusPainted(false);
    j.setBorderPainted(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, what are you expectations and how is the code not meeting them (ie you want to fill the area within the button and still have it's border ... which I might add would be near impossible without a lot of work)

Comment: I want it to fill within the button, but still have a border @MadProgrammer

Comment: Okay, mission (almost) impossible. The content area is filled by the look and feel delegate, which generally ignores all the color properties. It s prohibitively complex to try and generate a look and feel delegate for all your expected platforms which would allow you to achieve your desired results. You could write your own custom look and feel delegate to do it though, but that's still a bit of work to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so this is a hacked version and is based on the idea that you want to maintain the current "look and feel" of the button, but want to use a different fill color

This simply applies a "highlight" color over the button...

[image: Highlighted buttons]

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Transparency;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import org.kaizen.core.ui.ImageUtilities;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            HighlightButton btn = new HighlightButton("Help");
            btn.setMargin(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20));
            btn.setHighlight(new Color(255, 0, 0, 64));
            add(btn);

            btn = new HighlightButton("Help");
            btn.setMargin(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20));
            btn.setHighlight(new Color(0, 255, 0, 64));
            add(btn);

            btn = new HighlightButton("Help");
            btn.setMargin(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20));
            btn.setHighlight(new Color(0, 0, 255, 64));
            add(btn);

            btn = new HighlightButton("Help");
            btn.setMargin(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20));
            add(btn);
        }

    }

    public class HighlightButton extends JButton {

        private Color highlight;

        public HighlightButton() {
            setOpaque(false);
        }

        public HighlightButton(String text) {
            super(text);
            setOpaque(false);
        }

        public void setHighlight(Color color) {
            if (color != highlight) {
                Color old = highlight;
                this.highlight = color;
                firePropertyChange("highlight", old, highlight);
                repaint();
            }
        }

        public Color getHighlight() {
            return highlight;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Color highlight = getHighlight();
            if (highlight != null) {
                BufferedImage img = createCompatibleImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);
                Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
                super.paintComponent(g2d);
                g2d.dispose();

                BufferedImage mask = generateMask(img, getHighlight(), 1f);
                g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
                g.drawImage(mask, 0, 0, this);
            } else {
                super.paintComponent(g);
            }
        }

    }

    public static BufferedImage createCompatibleImage(int width, int height, int transparency) {
        BufferedImage image = getGraphicsConfiguration().createCompatibleImage(width, height, transparency);
        image.coerceData(true);
        return image;
    }

    public static GraphicsConfiguration getGraphicsConfiguration() {
        return GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();
    }

    public static BufferedImage generateMask(BufferedImage imgSource, Color color, float alpha) {

        int imgWidth = imgSource.getWidth();
        int imgHeight = imgSource.getHeight();

        BufferedImage imgMask = createCompatibleImage(imgWidth, imgHeight, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);
        Graphics2D g2 = imgMask.createGraphics();
        applyQualityRenderingHints(g2);

        g2.drawImage(imgSource, 0, 0, null);
        g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_IN, alpha));
        g2.setColor(color);

        g2.fillRect(0, 0, imgSource.getWidth(), imgSource.getHeight());
        g2.dispose();

        return imgMask;

    }

    public static void applyQualityRenderingHints(Graphics2D g2d) {
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
    }

}
```

Basically, what this does, is paints a "masked" image, colored in the highlighted color OVER the top of the button.  This is important to remember.  The higher the alpha value of the color becomes, the less likely you are to see the text.

I've not tested this on windows, so I can't guarantee the results.

The content filling is performed by the look and feel delegate and generally ignores the color properties of the class (yeah, I know, awesome), so if you want to try and do something which was a little more robust, you'd need to define your own look and feel delegate and take over the painting process, no simple task.

Of course, you could just dispense with the content filling and borders used by the look and feel delegate and paint your own (overriding the `paintComponent` method), but this will not take advantage of the look and feel settings, so that's a balancing act you need to decide on

Comment: Thank you for your help! I can't wait to implement this

Comment: Thank you for your help, but setFont is not working, is there any solution?

Comment: @VitVit It would depend a lot on if the font is system font or not and if it's not are you loading it properly.  Sounds more like an issue with loading/applying the font to a standard component then an issue with the example